# When trying to launch minecraft my launcher closes and then reopens instead

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I fix this?

```
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> #
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> #
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006903d238, pid=340, tid=8088
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> #
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # JRE version: 6.0_17-b04
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # Problematic frame:
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # C  [atio6axx.dll+0xd238]
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> #
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # C:\Users\Zach\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid340.log
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> #
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
[23:46:17 INFO]: Client> #
[23:46:17 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code 1)
[23:46:17 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[23:46:17 INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\Zach\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.5\1.7.5-natives-271016666110916
[23:46:17 WARN]: Couldn't delete C:\Users\Zach\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.5\1.7.5-natives-271016666110916 - scheduling for deletion upon exit
```

Answer (score 3):

atio6axx.dll is the AMD OpenGL driver. Reinstalling or updating that may fix the crash.

Answer (score -3):

Okay, so you need to download a new version file of your minecraft (.minecraft/versions/[your version name]) and name it whatever your version is, and delete the old one in there and finally, put the downloaded file into the versions folder while naming it the same as the old versions jar.

Comment: Why does this solve the issue?  There doesn't seem to be anything in the question that would point to a reinstall helping, let along solving.